# Idiomatic equivalent of « H/T » (hat tip) to credit in a tweet?

Tags: выражения

In English, tweeters will often tersely credit the originator of an idea using the contraction H/T (or HT) for *hat tip* followed by someone's name or handle.

What might be an idiomatic equivalent in Russian?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't tell about the Russian Twitter users, but in various Internet forums I've seen people use the copyright symbol "(C)":

> Да будет свет! (с) Бог

в значении

> Да будет свет!, как сказал Бог.

Clearly, "hat tip" has a wider meaning than just the indication of someone's authorship, so "(c)" probably cannot be used in all contexts where "HT" is appropriate.

Comment: (c) is a mark of citation, but it cannot be used if you mention the source of information without precisely quoting their words.

Comment: @Olga -- tell that to the people who use it, I'm just the messenger.

Answer (score 1):

There is no fixed equivalent, as far as I know.
Some people use "через" or "via", followed by the name of the user. It is the way Facebook does it if you repost someone's message, and many users carry this over to Twitter. For example:

> Не могу и не хочу в это верить. Но это так. Россия заняла второе место
>   по числу беженцев из страны
>   http://www.the-village.ru/village/city/city/141101-posle-sirii … via
>   @villagemsk
>
> В руки ФСБ попали тысячи чистых бланков украинских паспортов: ими
>   снабдят «дружинников» #odessa http://dumskaya.net/news/_307-034067/ …
>   через @dumskaya_net

Sometimes, people just use the RT and the name of the user for retweet:

> Есть и позитивные новости.. RT @RussiaKapnic: Корабль ВМС США сел на
>   мель в Черном море http://www.fontanka.ru/2014/02/19/007/  А они
>   думали в Рай попали!)

At the same time, I don't see many people use "HT" in Russian tweets. I also don't find people who use (c) in this context.